# Java Game Programming: Smooth Jumping

Tags: java, game-physics

For the past week and a half, I have been programming a game from scratch with Java and Swing. So far, the game has been working smoothly except for one thing: jumping. I'm trying to implement parabolic jumping so that the player doesn't just teleport a little bit up. Instead, I want it to look realistic. My code so far looks like this(this is only the jump method, it calls it whenever the space, W, or up keys are pressed):

```
private void jump(Game game){
    VectorF velocity = new VectorF(0f, 0.1f);       

    int t = 0;

    while(t < 200){
        if(checkTop(game)) break;

        relPos.sub(velocity);
        t++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got a question?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem with the given code is? And how exactly you call that method?

Comment: By the way, VectorF is a class I created to handle vector motion with floats. I also made VectorI which is essentially the same thing but with integers instead.

Comment: mastov The problem is that the player seems to teleport up a little bit, and I call the method with an if statement that has input.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)

Comment: input is an InputHandler, a class that handles key events and soon mouse events.

Comment: YassinH My question is how would I make jumping look like a parabolic arc so that jumping looks realistic. So far the player just teleports up.

Comment: Then you have to draw each frame on the parabolic trajectory, that is, draw inside the while loop.

Comment: You should have a thread for updating the player's position every x milliseconds and another one for repainting the view; with this, you can make the player jump just by changing their velocity once when the jump button is pressed, and applying gravity every 'tick' of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Your game should have a [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html).

Typically, a (very basic) game loop looks like:

```
while (playing) {
    accept_input()
    update_game_logic()
    render()
}
```

Within your `update_game_logic()` function you would have a section which updates the player's position. The player's position update step will often look like some mixture of:

```
// 1. sum up 'effects' on the player
    // think of 'effects' as velocities that we are adding together
    // is jumping? add (0.0, 0.1), 
    // is holding the right-button? add (0.1, 0.0)
// 2. add a gravity effect (0.0, -0.05)?
// 3. sum up all velocity changes and apply them to the player
// 4. check for any collision and prevent it 
    // (straight up adjusting the position out of the colliding object will do for now, this will also stop you from falling through the floor due to gravity)
```

Because you are adjusting the player's position based on velocity every tick, you can continue to accept input and render the screen whilst updating the game logic.

Edit: If you want a proper parabolic arc, the 'effects' above should actually be forces which add together to cause a change in velocity (through acceleration) and then change the position in a more realistic fashion. View [my similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687483/implementing-gravity-flipping-mechanics-using-c-win32/32687630#32687630) for more details.