# Implementing gravity flipping mechanics using C++ Win32

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm trying to think of an efficient way implementing gravity flipping mechanics into my C++ Win32 game. Although I'm not very fluent with the language, thats why I'm here to ask.

I have:

- A class which stores the properties of the player (such as position and size, as well as some functions).
- A Message Router which takes in messages sent from the user (and other sources).
- These messages include the player inputs. I handle the inputs in the Message Router and then call the functions on the player class.

I'm stuck on how to implement the gravity flipping mechanic. This is a free runner game. The player runs towards the right side of the window, and after a tap of a key the player character will alternate between normal (downwards) gravity or inverted (upwards) gravity.

The approach which I have taken into account is using a do-while. The problem with this is that the user must wait until the do-while is complete. That is, if the player hasn't reach to the top of the screen keep moving up (inverted gravity).

I have thought of other approaches but I don't think they're worth trying. It just leads to some other trouble.

Any suggestions anyone ?

Thanks in advance :)

**Update**

Here is the code ive been working on and the current problem that i have to is that once the player has reached to the bottom or top of the screen. I can't seem to change the gravity. But it allows me to do that before the player touches the top or bottom window edge.
Why is this ?

Feel free to criticize on my code and tell me how i can improve me.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "BaseWindow.h"
#include "GameWindow.h"

int APIENTRY WinMain ( HINSTANCE h_instance, HINSTANCE h_prev_instance, LPSTR lp_cmd_line, int n_cmd_show ) {
    // Create the Game Window
    GameWindow game_window ( h_instance, TEXT ( "GameWindow" ) );
    game_window.Register ();

    // Create the Base Window
    BaseWindow base_window ( TEXT ( "BaseWindow" ), game_window.ClassName () );
    base_window.Create ();
    base_window.Show ();

    // Pump Messages
    MSG messages;
    int status;
    while ( ( status = GetMessage ( &messages, 0, 0, 0 ) ) != 0 ) {
        if ( status == -1 ) {
            // Break;
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage ( &messages );
        DispatchMessage ( &messages );
    }
    return messages.wParam;

}
```

**AbstractWindow.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __ABSTRACT_WINDOW_H__
#define __ABSTRACT_WINDOW_H__

#include <Windows.h>

class AbstractWindow {
    public:
        AbstractWindow ();
        ~AbstractWindow ();

        virtual bool Create ();

        static LRESULT CALLBACK MessageRouter ( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

    protected:
        HWND hwnd_;

        DWORD style_ex_;
        LPCTSTR class_name_;
        LPCTSTR window_name_;
        DWORD style_;
        int x_;
        int y_;
        int width_;
        int height_;
        HWND parent_;
        HMENU menu_;
        HINSTANCE h_instance_;
        LPVOID param_;

        // Bitmap Variables - Start
        // Stucture for thw Window width and height
        RECT rect_;
        // Handle to Device Context
        HDC hdc_;
        // Handle to Device Context - Back Buffer
        HDC back_buffer_;
        // Bitmap - Front
        HBITMAP bitmap_; // Bitmap
        // Bitmap Variables - End


        // Default Handlers
        virtual bool OnCreate ( HWND ) = 0;
        virtual bool OnCommand ( int, int ) = 0;
        virtual bool OnDestroy () = 0;

        virtual bool OnPaint ( HWND, WPARAM ) = 0;

        // Player Handlers
        virtual bool UpdatePlayerPosition( HWND, WPARAM ) = 0;

};
#endif // !__ABSTRACT_WINDOW_H__
```

**AbstractWindow.cpp**

```
#include "AbstractWindow.h"

AbstractWindow::AbstractWindow () {}

AbstractWindow::~AbstractWindow () {}

bool AbstractWindow::Create () {
    hwnd_ = CreateWindowEx (
        style_ex_,
        class_name_,
        window_name_,
        style_,
        x_,
        y_,
        width_,
        height_,
        parent_,
        menu_,
        h_instance_,
        this                    // Pointer to this class instance
        );

    if ( hwnd_ ) {
        OnCreate(hwnd_);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK AbstractWindow::MessageRouter ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param ) {
    AbstractWindow* abstract_window = 0;

    static bool move = false;

    if ( message == WM_NCCREATE ) {
        abstract_window = ( AbstractWindow* ) ( ( LPCREATESTRUCT ( l_param ) )->lpCreateParams );
        SetWindowLong ( hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, long ( abstract_window ) );
        return DefWindowProc ( hwnd, message, w_param, l_param );
    }
    else {
        abstract_window = ( AbstractWindow* ) ( GetWindowLong ( hwnd, GWL_USERDATA ) );
        if ( abstract_window ) {
            switch ( message ) {
                case WM_COMMAND:
                    return abstract_window->OnCommand ( LOWORD ( w_param ), HIWORD ( w_param ) );
                case WM_DESTROY:
                    return abstract_window->OnDestroy ();
                case WM_PAINT:
                    return abstract_window->OnPaint ( hwnd, w_param);
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                    return abstract_window->UpdatePlayerPosition( hwnd, w_param );
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc ( hwnd, message, w_param, l_param );
            }
        }
        else {
            return DefWindowProc ( hwnd, message, w_param, l_param );
        }
    }
}

**BaseWindow.h**
#pragma once
#ifndef __BASE_WINDOW_H__
#define __BASE_WINDOW_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include "AbstractWindow.h"
#include "Player.h"

class BaseWindow : public AbstractWindow {
    public:
        BaseWindow ();
        ~BaseWindow ();

        BaseWindow ( const TCHAR*, const TCHAR* );

        // Display the window onto the screen while updating the client area
        void Show ();


    private:

        // Player Object
        Player player;  

        // Handlers
        virtual bool OnCreate ( HWND );
        virtual bool OnCommand ( int, int );
        virtual bool OnDestroy ();

        virtual bool OnPaint( HWND, WPARAM );

        // Player Handlers
        virtual bool UpdatePlayerPosition( HWND, WPARAM );


};
#endif // !__BASE_WINDOW_H__
```

**BaseWindow.cpp**

```
#include "BaseWindow.h"

#pragma region Constructor and Destructor

    BaseWindow::BaseWindow() {}

    BaseWindow::~BaseWindow() {}

    BaseWindow::BaseWindow( const TCHAR* window_name, const TCHAR* class_name ) : AbstractWindow() {
        // Member variables are declaried in AbstractWindow as Protected
        window_name_ = window_name;
        class_name_ = class_name;

        // Get the module handle for the window currently running
        h_instance_ = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
        style_ = ( WS_OVERLAPPED| WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX );
        x_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
        y_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
        width_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
        height_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
        parent_ = NULL;
        menu_ = NULL;

    }

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Functions

    void BaseWindow::Show() {
        // hwnd_ is from AbstractWindow Class
        ShowWindow( hwnd_, SW_SHOW );
        UpdateWindow( hwnd_ );
    }

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Basic Handlers

    bool BaseWindow::OnCreate( HWND hwnd ) {
        MessageBox( hwnd, TEXT( "[BaseWindow] Window has been successfully created!" ), TEXT( "SUCCESS" ), MB_OK );

        GetClientRect( hwnd, &rect_ );
        width_ = rect_.right;
        height_ = rect_.bottom;

        // Create the back buffer
        back_buffer_ = CreateCompatibleDC( NULL );
        // Get the Device Context
        hdc_ = GetDC( hwnd );
        // Create the Bitmap
        bitmap_ = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc_, width_, height_ );
        // Select the Bitmap
        SelectObject( back_buffer_, bitmap_ );
        // Release
        ReleaseDC( hwnd, hdc_ );

        return true;
    }

    bool BaseWindow::OnCommand( int ctrl_id, int notify_code ) {

        // Lower 16 bits specifies the element the mouse was used on
        // Upper 16 bits specifies the mouse properties
        // ctrl_id = Lower
        // notify_code = Upper
        return true;
    }

    bool BaseWindow::OnDestroy() {
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return true;
    }

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Other Handlers

    bool BaseWindow::OnPaint( HWND hwnd, WPARAM w_param ) {

        PAINTSTRUCT paint_struct;

        // Get the Device Context
        hdc_ = BeginPaint( hwnd, &paint_struct );

        BitBlt( back_buffer_, 0, 0, width_, height_, NULL, NULL, NULL, WHITENESS );

        if ( player.WithinTopBounds() && player.WithinBottomBounds(height_) ) {
            player.GravityMovement();
        }


        // Select the Rectangle Brush
        SelectObject( back_buffer_, CreateSolidBrush( RGB( player.SpecializerRed(), player.SpecializerGreen(), player.SpecializerBlue() ) ) );
        // Draw the Rectangle on the back buffer
        Rectangle( back_buffer_,
                   player.X() - player.Width() / 2,
                   player.Y() - player.Height() / 2,
                   player.X() + player.Width() / 2,
                   player.Y() + player.Height() / 2);

        // Display the back buffer
        BitBlt( hdc_, 0, 0, width_, height_, back_buffer_, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );
        // Repaint the screen
        InvalidateRect( hwnd, NULL, false );

        EndPaint( hwnd, &paint_struct );

        return true;
    }

    #pragma region Player

        bool BaseWindow::UpdatePlayerPosition(HWND hwnd, WPARAM w_param ) {
            if ( w_param == VK_RIGHT ) {
                if ( player.withinRightBounds( width_ ) ) {
                    // Movement to the right
                    player.RightMovement();
                }
            }
            if ( w_param == VK_LEFT ) {
                if ( player.WithinLeftBounds() ) {
                    // Movement to right left
                    player.LeftMovement();
                }           
            }

            if ( w_param == VK_UP ) {               
                // Movement upwards
                if ( !player.WithinTopBounds() ) {
                    player.SetInverted( false );
                }
                player.SetInverted( true );

            }
            if ( w_param == VK_DOWN ) {
                if ( !player.WithinBottomBounds( height_ ) ) {
                    player.SetInverted( true );
                }
                // Movement downwards
                player.SetInverted( false );

            }

            return true;
        }

    #pragma endregion



#pragma endregions
```

**GameWindow.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __GAME_WINDOW_H__
#define __GAME_WINDOW_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include "AbstractWindow.h"

class GameWindow : protected WNDCLASSEX {
    public:
        GameWindow ();
        ~GameWindow ();

        GameWindow ( HINSTANCE, const TCHAR* );

        virtual bool Register ();

        virtual const TCHAR* ClassName () const;

    protected:
        UINT cb_size_;
        UINT style_;
        WNDPROC lpfn_wnd_proc_;
        int cb_cls_extra_;
        int cb_wnd_extra_;
        HINSTANCE h_instance_;
        HICON h_icon_;
        HCURSOR h_cursor_;
        HBRUSH hbr_background_;
        LPCTSTR lpsz_menu_name_;
        LPCTSTR lpsz_class_name_;
        HICON h_icon_sm_;


};
#endif // !__GAME_WINDOW_H__


**GameWindow.cpp**

#include "GameWindow.h"

GameWindow::GameWindow () {}

GameWindow::~GameWindow () {}

GameWindow::GameWindow ( HINSTANCE h_instance, const TCHAR* class_name ) {

    // All messages belonging to this Window Class will get sent to MsgRouter

    hInstance = h_instance;
    lpszClassName = class_name;

    lpfnWndProc = AbstractWindow::MessageRouter;
    lpszMenuName = NULL;
    cbSize = sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX );
    cbClsExtra = NULL;
    cbWndExtra = NULL;
    // Prevent Window from Redrawing
    style = 0;
    hIcon = LoadIcon ( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    hIconSm = LoadIcon ( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    hCursor = LoadCursor ( NULL, IDC_HAND );
    hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush ( RGB ( 125, 255, 255 ) );

}

const TCHAR* GameWindow::ClassName () const {
    return lpszClassName;
}

bool GameWindow::Register () {
    return ( ( RegisterClassEx ( this ) ) ? true : false );
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __PLAYER_H__
#define __PLAYER_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Player {
    public:
        Player ();
        ~Player ();

        // Mutator
        void SetX ( float );
        void SetY ( float );
        void SetPlayerSpeed ( float );

        void SetSpecializerState ( string );
        void SetInverted( bool );

        // Accessor
        float X () const;
        float Y () const;
        int Width () const;
        int Height () const;

        int SpecializerRed () const;
        int SpecializerGreen () const;
        int SpecializerBlue () const;
        string SpecializerState () const;

        bool Inverted() const;


        // Player Functionality
        void RightMovement ();
        void LeftMovement ();
        void GravityMovement();
        // Within Bounds Detection
        bool WithinLeftBounds();
        bool withinRightBounds(int);
        bool WithinTopBounds();
        bool WithinBottomBounds(int);


    private:
        // General Information
        float x_;
        float y_;
        int width_;
        int height_;
        float speed_;
        float gravity_;
        bool inverted_;

        // Player States
        int specializer_state_;
        // RGB
        int specializer_red_;
        int specializer_green_;
        int specializer_blue_;

        void SetSpecializerColor (int);


};

#endif // !__PLAYER_H__
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"


#pragma region Constructor and Destructor

Player::Player () {

    x_ = 200;
    y_ = 200;
    width_ = 50;
    height_ = 50;
    speed_ = 5.0f;
    gravity_ = 0.2f;
    inverted_ = false;

    // Specializer
    // Set to Default Specializer State
    specializer_state_ = 0;
    specializer_red_ = 0;
    specializer_green_ = 0;
    specializer_blue_ = 0;
    SetSpecializerColor ( specializer_state_ );

}

Player::~Player () {}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Mutator

    #pragma region Position Properties

    void Player::SetX ( float x ) {
        x_ = x;
    }
    void Player::SetY ( float y ) {
        y_ = y;
    }

    #pragma endregion

    void Player::SetInverted( bool inverted ) {
        inverted_ = inverted;
    }

    #pragma region Specializer Properties

    void Player::SetSpecializerState ( string input_state ) {

        if ( input_state == "NORMAL" ) {
            specializer_state_ = 0;
        }
        else if ( input_state == "SHIELD" ) {
            specializer_state_ = 1;
        }
        else if ( input_state == "SPEED" ) {
            specializer_state_ = 2;
        }
        else if ( input_state == "PROJECTILE" ) {
            specializer_state_ = 3;
        }
        else if ( input_state == "MULTIPLIER" ) {
            specializer_state_ = 4;
        }

        SetSpecializerColor ( specializer_state_ );

    }

    void Player::SetSpecializerColor ( int state ) {
        if ( specializer_state_ == 0 ) {
            // NORMAL - White
            specializer_red_ = 255;
            specializer_green_ = 255;
            specializer_blue_ = 255;
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 1 ) {
            // SHIELD - Green
            specializer_red_ = 255;
            specializer_green_ = 153;
            specializer_blue_ = 76;
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 2 ) {
            // SPEED - Blue
            specializer_red_ = 0;
            specializer_green_ = 0;
            specializer_blue_ = 102;
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 3 ) {
            // PROJECTILE - Yellow
            specializer_red_ = 255;
            specializer_green_ = 255;
            specializer_blue_ = 0;
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 4 ) {
            // MULTIPLIER - Red
            specializer_red_ = 204;
            specializer_green_ = 0;
            specializer_blue_ = 0;
        }
    }

    #pragma endregion



#pragma endregion

#pragma region Accessor

    #pragma region Position Properties

    float Player::X () const {
        return x_;
    }

    float Player::Y () const {
        return y_;
    }

    int Player::Width () const {
        return width_;
    }

    int Player::Height () const {
        return height_;
    }

    bool Player::Inverted() const {
        return inverted_;
    }

    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Specializer Properties

    int Player::SpecializerRed () const {
        return specializer_red_;
    }

    int Player::SpecializerGreen () const {
        return specializer_green_;
    }

    int Player::SpecializerBlue () const {
        return specializer_blue_;
    }

    string Player::SpecializerState () const {

        string specializer_state = "";

        if ( specializer_state_ == 0 ) {
            specializer_state = "NORMAL";
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 1 ) {
            specializer_state = "SHIELD";
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 2 ) {
            specializer_state = "SPEED";
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 3 ) {
            specializer_state = "PROJECTILE";
        }
        else if ( specializer_state_ == 4 ) {
            specializer_state = "MULTIPLIER";
        }

        return specializer_state;
    }

    #pragma endregion

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Functionality

    #pragma region Movement

        void Player::RightMovement() {
            x_ += speed_;
        }

        void Player::LeftMovement() {
            x_ -= speed_;
        }

        void Player::GravityMovement() {
            if ( inverted_ ) {
                // Upwards
                if ( min( 0.0f, gravity_ ) == 0.0f ) {
                    gravity_ = -gravity_;
                }
                y_ += gravity_;
            }
            else {
                // Downwards
                if ( max( 0.0f, gravity_ ) == 0.0f ) {
                    gravity_ = -gravity_;
                }
                y_ += gravity_;
            }
        }

    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Within Window Bounds


        bool Player::WithinLeftBounds() {
            if ( x_ - ( width_ / 2 ) > 0 ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool Player::withinRightBounds( int width ) {
            if ( x_ + (width_ / 2) < width ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool Player::WithinTopBounds() {
            if ( y_ - ( height_ / 2 ) > 0 ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool Player::WithinBottomBounds( int height ) {
            if ( y_ + ( height_ / 2 ) < height ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    #pragma endregion


#pragma endregion
```

Comment: When I implement gravity in most of my games I use a velocity variable. Every tick (usually 1/60th of a second) I'll add positive acceleration to the y axis. Using collision resolution the player object doesn't fall through the floor, and everything feels natural. Inverting gravity would be as simple as `yVelocity *= -1`

Comment: How would i keep the gravity updating and window repainting while allowing other inputs from the user ?

Comment: Don't pause waiting for user input, allow the game to move fluidly, and have it respond to events when they occur. You can still use your response system, just augment that with a game loop.

Comment: Then what handle do i pass it to ?

Comment: `CreateSolidBrush` is causing serious resource leak. You have to call `DeleteObject` when you no longer need the brush. Use this instead: `HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(...); SelectObject(...); Rectangle(...); DeleteObject(brush);` --- Remove `InvalidateRect` in `OnPaint`. Instead put `InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, 0)` in `UpdatePlayerPosition` function (third parameter of `InvalidateRect` is zero because it doesn't need to erase background in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game should have a [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html).

Typically, a (very basic) game loop looks like:

```
while (playing) {
    accept_input()
    update_game_logic()
    render()
}
```

Within your `update_game_logic()` function you would have a section which updates the player's position. The player's position update step will often look like some mixture of:

```
// 1. sum up forces on the player (i.e. running to the right)
// 2. add current_gravity (normal or inverted)
// 3. check for any collision and add an opposing force 
    // (if touching the ground add a force directly opposite the ground, equal to the force the object is pushing down with)
// 4. resolve position using some form of integration
    // e.g. add force (* deltatime) to acceleration, add acceleration (* deltatime) to velocity, add velocity (* deltatime) to position.
```

Because you are adjusting the player's position based on forces every tick, you can continue to accept input and render the screen whilst updating the game logic.

Comment: Since im using a switch case to handle my messages. Would i add a function in the default before DefWindowProc to apply the x and y movement ? x for moving like a free runner and y for gravity ?

Comment: It sounds like you're over-complicating the issue. I'd recommend reading through the link in my post and then re-consider your architecture a little bit.

Comment: Okay so . . after reading through that link. I think the approach that i should take is in the switch case where i handle my messages. I should check whether inverted gravity should be applied. If yes, then apply it else, apply normal gravity.

Comment: Sounds much better! :)

Please accept the answer if your query is solved :)

Comment: Actually I have a small question. Since im using a switch case for handling the message. I dont know which handler do i put it for. WM_PAINT ?

Comment: That is very much a different problem. I don't know what your architecture is and without seeing your code I can't help you.